# how can i organize my array with pointers, without using [] operator

Tags: c, function, pointers

I need to organize my array to find the median number. I can't use _[] operator in my question and I can't see why my code doesn't work

```
    int Median(int* numbers, int size)
{
    int temp;
    int *num_tmp = numbers;
    int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i< size - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j< size; j++) {
            if (*(num_tmp+1) < num_tmp) {
                temp = num_tmp;
                num_tmp = (num_tmp+1);
                *(num_tmp+1) = temp;
           }
         }
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...amazing.. it works..

Comment: I think it's the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: If you are using a compiler - didn't it complain?

Comment: it compiled without any complains

Comment: @dvir.: How do you compile the program?

Comment: with visual studio 2016

Comment: @dvir.:You have to configure the compiler invocation so that it is called appropriately with proper flags.

Comment: @dvir.: Just make sure you enable compiler warning - otherwise you will create lots of problem for yourself. Next thing you will do will be to check how to enable compiler warnings and read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ once. It will make things much more clear on how to approach these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the idea but didn't use it correctly.

```
if (*(num_tmp+1) < num_tmp)
    ^ ^^^^^^^^     ^^^^
   An int value    A pointers value
```

You are comparing an address with an `int` variable. You don't want that. Changing a bit would yield,

```
if (*(num_tmp+1) < *num_tmp)
```

Now ask is it logically right? No. The algorithm is still wrong.

It should be

```
if (*(num_tmp+j) < *(num_tmp+i))
{
     temp = *(num_tmp+j);
     *(num_tmp+j) = *(num_tmp+i);
     *(num_tmp+i) = temp;
}
```

With this code you will organize the array correctly.

Also if you are using `gcc` to compile the program add `-Wall -Werror` that will show you all the warnings.